# Python subprocess check_output FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I wrote a little python script to build and test my docker images of that project. The script runs well locally, but fails remotely during `check_output`.

build.py

```py
    print(check_output(["which", "dgoss"]))
    result = str(check_output(["dgoss", "run", image_tag], cwd=image_path, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL))
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
    before_script:
      - curl -fsSL https://goss.rocks/install | sh
      - ls -la /usr/local/bin/ | grep goss
    script:
      - which dgoss
      - python3 ./infrastructure/build.py
```

Output

```sh
dgoss master has been installed to /usr/local/bin/dgoss
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/ | grep goss
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          3803 May 17 08:58 dgoss
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       8524064 May 17 08:58 goss
$ which dgoss
/usr/local/bin/dgoss
$ python3 ./infrastructure/build.py
infrastructure/broker
b'/usr/local/bin/dgoss\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./infrastructure/build.py", line 54, in <module>
    test()
  File "./infrastructure/build.py", line 42, in test
    result = str(check_output(["dgoss", "run", image_tag], cwd=image_path, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dgoss': 'dgoss'
```

The file is present and executable. Why does python throw the exception?

Comment: What `check_output` does? It obviously look for a file names `dgoss` and can not find it, what is this file?

Comment: You should try to call `dgoss` command with full path. Like this: `result = str(check_output([str(check_output(["which", "dgoss"])).strip(), "run", image_tag],...` Of course, you can create a separated variable for path of `dgoss`.

Comment: Tried full path, didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out dgoss is a bash wrapper around goss and alpine docker images ship without bash.

```
before_script:
  - apk add curl python3 bash
```